# Flutter/Dart : How to get MAC Address devices on the local network

Tags: flutter, dart, networking, ip-address, mac-address

So as the title suggests, I am trying to gather MAC Addresses from connected devices on my local network. Any idea on how I can achieve this would be helpful!

This is what I have made so far to find connected devices MAC Addresses :

```
  Future<String> getMacAddress(String ip) async {
// Use the ping command to check if the device is reachable
final ProcessResult pingResult = await Process.run(
  'ping',
  ['-c', '1', '-w', '1', ip],
);
if (pingResult.exitCode == 0) {
  // Use the netcfg command to get the MAC address of the device
  final ProcessResult netcfgResult = await Process.run(
    'netcfg',
    ['wlan0'],
  );
  if (netcfgResult.exitCode == 0) {
    final String output = netcfgResult.stdout;
    final List<String> lines = output.split('\n');
    for (final line in lines) {
      final List<String> parts = line.split(' ');
      if (parts.length >= 3 && parts[2] == ip) {
        return parts[3]; // Return the MAC address as a string
      }
    }
  }
}
return ''; // Return an empty string if the MAC address is not found
```

}

Comment: Show us some code, then we can help you.

Comment: Just did, you can check the edited version :)

Comment: It might be impossible to get the mac address in newer iOS phones if i remember correctly.

Comment: In my knowledge, you get a default MAC address for your own Device start something like 02:00:00... I believe that there is not limitation on finding MAC addresses of other devices on your local network. Also some apps on the Google Play Store achieve that.

Answer (score -3):

```
 import 'dart:io';

Future<String> getMacAddress() async {
   var interfaces = await NetworkInterface.list();
    var macAddress = '';

  for (var interface in interfaces) {
     // Convert the hardwareAddress list to a string
       macAddress = interface.hardwareAddress.join(':');
    break;
   }

  return macAddress;
}
```

Comment: The getter 'macAddress' isn't defined for the type 'NetworkInterface'.